# How to configure user environment to use the latest node runtime

Tags: node.js

We initialize node.js using **nvm use 0.10.0**
How to configure user environment to use the latest node runtime, so that the bash shell gets initialized when I launch a new terminal in Ubuntu

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
nvm use 0.10.0
```

Comment: which nvm doesn't show anything
nvm use 0.10.0 (sets it, but if I add in .bashrc it says command not found)
Now using node v0.10.0

Answer (score 1):

posting this answer for future reference and help.

1st run the following command in the bash.

```
nvm alias default <the default version you want to set>
```

then put this in your .bashrc

```
export NVM_DIR="path/to/.nvm/folder" #<-edit with real value
if [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ]; then
    source "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
fi
NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=$(<"$NVM_DIR/alias/default")
export PATH="$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION/bin":$PATH
```

and, `source .bashrc`

the advantage of this setup is that, whatever node you will install and set as default, it will be available for all bash sessions.