# nvm keeps "forgetting" node in new terminal session

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew, nvm

### Upon using a new terminal session in OS X, `nvm` forgets the node version and defaults to nothing:

`$ nvm ls`:

```
         .nvm
     v0.11.12
     v0.11.13
```

I have to keep hitting `nvm use v.0.11.13` in every session:

```
         .nvm
     v0.11.12
->   v0.11.13
```

I've tried both the `brew` install, as well as the official installation script.

My **`.profile`** for the brew version:

```
#nvm
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

And for the install.sh script:

`$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.10.0/install.sh | bash`

```
#nvm
export NVM_DIR="/Users/farhad/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

### Any clue to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just want to add this here - Make sure you export from `.bash_profile` and not your `.bashrc`

Comment: what's difference between .bash_profile vs .bashrc on Mac OS ?

Answer (score 1616, accepted):

Try `nvm alias default`. For example:

`$ nvm alias default 0.12.7`

This sets the default node version in your shell. Then verify that the change persists by closing the shell window, opening a new one, then:
`node --version`

Comment: Was not working for me, and I didn't have the problem maxwell states.  I didn't use brew but I upgraded/reinstalled my nvm and that fixed it.

Comment: My version of nvm (1.1.0) does not recognize the alias parameter

Comment: Also, depending on where the nvm init script is loaded in your profile, it's possible that a new shell doesn't load the expected version, even with the default aliased properly.

Comment: If that doesn't work, make sure in your `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc` or whatever) you don't have anything modifying `PATH` after `source xx/nvm.sh`

Comment: @KellyS.French (nvm maintainer here) nvm has never yet hit 1.0 - you may have installed it off of npm. Install only using the curl script at http://nvm.sh and you'll get the right version.

Comment: @LJHarb I'll try that. It does make me wonder how my environment was translating my 'nvm' command. I installed nvm by downloading the Windows binary so is there a .bat or .ps1 equivalent of the curl script you mentioned?

Comment: @KellyS.French ah! nvm does not support windows (except for BashOnWindows) - you may have nvm-windows, which is a different project.

Comment: you can also specify a `lts` version in later version of `nvm`. e.g.: `nvm alias default lts/boron`

Comment: I cannot get this to work on an Amazon linux image. I have tried the above and defining use, etc... I have to manually run: `nvm use 8.8.1` everytime. this is a pain. NVM is too broken. I am just manually installing node. No issues this way.

Comment: I actually had to uninstall the version that was used by default since nothing else worked out. `$ nvm uninstall 6.11.3` and then I switched to 6.11.5...

Comment: The behaviour is very confusing.  The first nvm install X sets your nvm alias default to X, which is what you'll get in a new shell until you do another nvm use or nvm install.  Even if you do nvm use or nvm install, that won't update nvm alias so you're stuck with the first default version unless you update the alias yourself.

Comment: This answer worked for me on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: ffs this was such an easy answer, this has been bugging me for a while and thought it was going to be some annoying path thing to fix, thank you.

Comment: Instead of pinning Node to a version, you can specify `'lts/*'` as the version identifier to use the latest LTS version.

Comment: That works perfectly fine, but why use stopped working?

Comment: `nvm alias default stable`

Comment: Doesn't persist. I tried installing nvm, everything works, but when I remove that node version it says it's not installed, but when I check node version it comes up?

Comment: In fish with jorgebucaran/nvm.fish I get `nvm: Unknown command or option: "alias" (see nvm -h)`. I guess there you need to use `set --universal nvm_default_version $VERSION`

Comment: This no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 184):

Alias to `node` itself to avoid updating the default alias along with node version updates later on.

```
nvm alias default node
```

Comment: This is actually better than aliasing to a specific version (the other answer). It is also the approach suggested at https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script .

Comment: If setting default alias does not work,
1. Try moving the `export NVM_DIR=....` in bash profile to the last
2. If that also does not work, uninstall nvm and reinstall it and install the node version you want
Don't spend too much time finding a fix. reinstall is very quick

Comment: Seems this approach no longer works (2022-11-15). As per the docs, `node` is itself is an alias to the latest version on your system. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#usage

Comment: This should be the top answer, but I guess it never will. Voters don't always choose the right choice...Sad.

Answer (score 104):

In my case, another program had added `PATH` changes to `.bashrc`

If the other program changed the `PATH` *after* nvm's initialisation, then nvm's `PATH` changes would be forgotten, and we would get the system node on our `PATH` (or no node).

**The solution was to move the nvm setup to the *bottom* of `.bashrc`**

```sh
### BAD .bashrc ###

# NVM initialisation
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

# Some other program adding to the PATH:
export PATH="$ANT_ROOT:$PATH"
```

Solution:

```sh
### GOOD .bashrc ###

# Some other program adding to the PATH:
export PATH="$ANT_ROOT:$PATH"

# NVM initialisation
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

(This was with bash 4.2.46 on CentOS.  It seems to me like a bug in bash, but I may be mistaken.)

Comment: Give this guy a medal! I had additional loading of other *rc files in my zshrc after the NVM_DIR export it drove me crazy. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me bonkers.

Comment: Please clarify why you didn't use "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" after export statement ?

Comment: @vikramvi We did, on the last line. `\.` is the same as `source`. The `[ -s ... ]` just checks that the file exists and is not empty. If you are asking why not move _just_ the source line to the bottom, and leave the `export NVM_DIR` where it was originally, the only reason is to keep the NVM lines together for clarity. You could separate them if you wanted to.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. Otherwise I was seeing the default revert with each new terminal.

Comment: I don't understand, why would an entirely unrelated path in the `$PATH` variable affect node version? Was your "other program" modifying the node path?

Comment: @MuhsinFatih What seems to happen is when `export PATH="$ANT_ROOT:$PATH"` executes, for some reason bash uses an earlier copy of `PATH`, ignoring the directory that nvm added. The result is that we don't have nvm's directory on the `PATH` at all. It gets "forgotten".

Comment: Is there not a better way to fix the nvm addition to PATH by making sure it somehow persists in the PATH? Since other stuff might always update PATH later so this is super annoying to have to ensure nvm is always list in my dotfiles

Comment: oh my god. this helped me. it works.

Comment: @rasen58 Does installing bash 5 fix the issue?

Answer (score 55):

To install the latest stable version:

```
nvm install stable
```

To set default to the stable version (instead of a specific version):

```
nvm alias default stable
```

To list installed versions:

```
nvm list
```

As of `v6.2.0`, it will look something like:

```
$ nvm list
         v4.4.2
->       v6.2.0
default -> stable (-> v6.2.0)
node -> stable (-> v6.2.0) (default)
stable -> 6.2 (-> v6.2.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
```

Comment: This worked great and the suggestion to use `nvm list` helps users visualize what is happening with their versioning. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

None of these solutions worked in my environment, nvm always seems to load the first installed version of node no matter what (unless you change it temporarily via `nvm use`).

The only way to change the default I have found is to:

- Clear nvm cache: `nvm cache clear`
- Set default to desired version: `nvm alias default 12` (or whatever version)
- Switch to desired version: `nvm use 12`
- Uninstall all other versions:

  - `nvm ls` (to list installations)
  - `nvm uninstall x` (run for each installation that is not the default)
- Reinstall other versions: `nvm install x`

You can use this script to automate this process (just change the first variable to your desired version) - it will re-install all versions you had previously automatically.

```sh
DEFAULT_NVM_VERSION=16
nvm cache clear
nvm install $DEFAULT_NVM_VERSION
nvm alias default $DEFAULT_NVM_VERSION
NVERS=$(nvm ls --no-alias | grep -v -- "->" | grep -o "v[0-9.]*")
while read ver; do nvm uninstall $ver; done <<< $NVERS
while read ver; do nvm install $ver; done <<< $NVERS
nvm use $DEFAULT_NVM_VERSION
```

Or as a one-liner:

```sh
DEFAULT_NVM_VERSION=16 && nvm cache clear && nvm install $DEFAULT_NVM_VERSION && nvm alias default $DEFAULT_NVM_VERSION && NVERS=$(nvm ls --no-alias | grep -v -- "->" | grep -o "v[0-9.]*") && while read ver; do nvm uninstall $ver; done <<< $NVERS && while read ver; do nvm install $ver; done <<< $NVERS && nvm use $DEFAULT_NVM_VERSION
```

New terminals should now respect the default version.

Comment: Thank you! None of the other solutions worked for me either. Maybe this is a recent nvm bug.

Comment: Thanks but what is the point of putting it all on one line?  The line that fixed it for me was `nvm alias default 16`

Comment: @Phil this solution is for when the `nvm alias default` command doesn’t work (it doesn’t work for a lot of folks here it seems)

Comment: This is the only thing I could get to work, thanks.

Comment: doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 32):

nvm does its job by changing the PATH variable, so you need to make sure you aren't somehow changing your PATH to something else after sourcing the nvm.sh script.

In my case, nvm.sh was being called in .bashrc but then the PATH variable was getting updated in .bash_profile which caused my session to find the system node before the nvm node.

Comment: how can I inspect this? I suspect this is the case.

Comment: this was my case thanks! i was setting the export on top on my .zshrc file, just move it to the bottom and the problem was solved

Comment: That was my case. Solution was to move NVM ~/.bash_profile entry to the end of the file + set `nvm alias default` and `nvm use` to the version i needed.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Moved the following to the bottom of `.bashrc`: `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"` then
`. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"`

Comment: Same senario. I moved nvm script from `.bashrc` to `.bash_profile`, but that still didn't work. Then I set `nvm alias default` and move nvm script back to `.bashrc`. Problem solved.

Comment: Same applies for `.zshrc` if you're on a modern Mac circa 2024

Answer (score 31):

## Here is a simple instruction:

**1) Install:**

```
nvm install 8.10.0
```

**2) Use once per terminal**

```
nvm use 8.10.0
```

**3) Set up as default for all terminals**

```
nvm alias default 8.10.0
```

You may need to use root permissions to perform those actions.

And don't forget to check [nvm documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for more info.

Also note that you may need to specify node version for your IDE:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! In my case it worked by running this in vs code terminal: nvm use 16.14.2 and then restart VS Code. Beautiful!

Comment: Thanks you alot saved a hour of searching! none of answer worked for me... i was looking for `nvm use <version>`

Answer (score 14):

The top rated solutions didn't seem to work for me. My solution is below:

1. Uninstall nvm completely using homebrew:`brew uninstall nvm`
2. Reinstall `brew install nvm`
3. In Terminal, follow the steps
   below(these are also listed when installing nvm via homebrew):

   > mkdir ~/.nvm
   >       cp $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm-exec ~/.nvm/
   >       export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
   >       source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

The steps outlined above will add NVM's working directory to your $HOME path, copy nvm-exec to NVM's working directory and add to $HOME/.bashrc, $HOME/.zshrc, or your shell's equivalent configuration file.(again taken from whats listed on an NVM install using homebrew)

Answer (score 9):

If you have tried everything still no luck you can try this :_

1 -> Uninstall NVM

```
rm -rf ~/.nvm
```

2 -> Remove npm dependencies by following [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm)

3 -> [Install NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script)

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

4 -> Set `~/.bash_profile` configuration

Run `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

Copy and paste following this

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

5 -> `CONTROL + X` save the changes

6 -> Run  `. ~/.bash_profile`

7 -> Now you should have `nvm` installed on your machine, to install node run `nvm install v7.8.0` this will be default node version or you can install any version of node

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the only solution which sets node path in bash as well and worked for me.  I just used "nvm install node" to install latest node version rather than using "nvm install v7.8.0"

Comment: I don't think you need upped privileges via `sudo` in **4**. I'll edit the answer to remove, as there appears to be no benefit to privilege escalation here, as the answer works within the home directory. If that's not the case, I am curious to hear why--thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I'm using ZSH so I had to modify `~/.zshrc` with the lines concerning NVM in that order:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. this solution is easiest if any one is facing issue on ZSH.

Answer (score 7):

This question has mentioned for the OSX, but it happened to me in my linux OS.
I tried using `nvm alias default <version>` but for each new terminal session the used node version was forgotten.
so, here is the solution that i figured out.

**make sure to set a default alias for node version**,put the following code in .bashrc, and `source .bashrc`.

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/bonnie/.nvm"
## If the file exists and is not empty
if [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ]; then
    ## Source it
    source "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
fi
NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=$(<"$NVM_DIR/alias/default")
export PATH="$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION/bin":$PATH
```

[descriptive solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675707/how-to-configure-user-environment-to-use-the-latest-node-runtime/33859538#33859538)

Comment: Just a note, this relies on including the `v` in the version when setting the remote. E.g. `v4.2.4` instead of `4.2.4`.

Answer (score 5):

## Linux/ubuntu

how to solve this you can see [here](https://i.ibb.co/vQpMrpb/2022-11-19-18-14.jpg)

- https://i.ibb.co/vQpMrpb/2022-11-19-18-14.jpg

`nvm use` isn't meant to persist - it's only for the lifetime of the shell.

You can either do `nvm alias default node` if you want that to be the default when opening new shells or, you can make a `.nvmrc` file that will take precedence anywhere in the current directory, upwards to `/`.
[https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/658](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/658#issuecomment-74147703)

[image: ubutnu-terminal]

Comment: Most explanatory!

Answer (score 4):

Doing `nvm install 10.14`, for example, will `nvm use` that version for the current shell session but it will *not* always set it as the default for future sessions as you would expect.  The node version you get in a new shell session is determined by `nvm alias default`.  Confusingly, `nvm install` will only set the default alias if it is not already set.  To get the expected behaviour, do this:

```
nvm alias default ''; nvm install 10.14
```

This will ensure that that version is downloaded, use it for the current session *and* set it as the default for future sessions.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue while using the integrated terminal in VS Code editor. Restarting VS Code after changing the node version using nvm fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

- I use NVM with zsh bash
- [follow this link to remove nvm](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/how+to+uninstall+nvm+on+mac)
- `$ brew install nvm`
- I ran this line `$ source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh` after installation and restart terminal
- place the line bellow in `~/.zshrc` file, also instructed by [nvm official GitHub page](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#zsh)

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

# place this after nvm initialization!
autoload -U add-zsh-hook

load-nvmrc() {
  local node_version="$(nvm version)"
  local nvmrc_path="$(nvm_find_nvmrc)"

  if [ -n "$nvmrc_path" ]; then
    local nvmrc_node_version=$(nvm version "$(cat "${nvmrc_path}")")

    if [ "$nvmrc_node_version" = "N/A" ]; then
      nvm install
    elif [ "$nvmrc_node_version" != "$node_version" ]; then
      nvm use
    fi
  elif [ "$node_version" != "$(nvm version default)" ]; then
    echo "Reverting to nvm default version"
    nvm use default
  fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd load-nvmrc
load-nvmrc
```

Comment: It can be simplify to `nvm use default >> /dev/null 2>&1`
I use zsh and I found that the accepted answer doesn't work. I think on zsh, this might be the best(only?) choice.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason in my **.bashrc** file I found this:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" --no-use  # This loads nvm
```

and had to remove **--no-use** flag, which I don't remember putting there in a first place...
Just another thing to check.

Answer (score 3):

On my end, I had to change both aliases STABLE and DEFAULT

```
nvm alias stable {node_version}

nvm alias default {node_version}
```

Answer (score 2):

run this after you installed any version,

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

This command is copying whatever version of node you have active via nvm into the /usr/local/ directory and setting the permissions so that all users can access them.

Comment: I would recommend using `&&`s instead of `;`s in that command. If the `which` fails to find node, we don't want to proceed to chmod `/bin/*`!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a new way here. Using `n` [Interactively Manage Your Node.js](https://github.com/tj/n)  helps.

Comment: Yes! Not sure if it's 'cause I'm using `fish` shell, but the accepted answer didn't work for me. `n` works a treat!

Answer (score 2):

If you also have SDKMAN...

Somehow SDKMAN was conflicting with my NVM. If you're at your wits end with this and still can't figure it out, I just fixed it by ignoring the "THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE..." from SDKMAN and putting the NVM lines after it.

```
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="/Users/myname/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/Users/myname/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/myname/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 1):

Also in case you had **node** installed before **nvm** check in your **~/.bash_profile** to not have something like :

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

If you do have it, comment/remove it and **nvm** should start handling the default node version.

Comment: Setting a path variable has nothing to do with the nvm version selection, surely?

Comment: nvm.sh should modify your PATH _after_ you set it (e.g. with the above).  This let nvm put its version directory _before_ /usr/local/bin where the "system" version of node lives.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the repository's issues section, `nvm use` is just for a lifetime of the shell. I have found this very useful, but sometimes it may put you in trouble actually when you are working on different codebases which need different versions of code.
This is the [link](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/658) for the related discussion in GitHub

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, in my `~/.profile` file I found that was selecting the version of node, overriding the `alias default` command of nvm

Just another thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything above but nothing worked. How I fixed this error is setting the default alias to the desired version and then in .zshrc (or bash rc if is your case) at the bottom level:

```
nvm use default
```

Is not the best approach but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, ${HOME}/node_modules existed and this is where the version of node was obtained. I moved it, tried again and it worked. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ nvm alias default {NODE_VERSION}
```

when we use the above command, only update the node version but the `npm` still uses the old version.

Here is another solution for update the both `node` and `npm`, in my case i want to use node `8.9.4` and i have used the below command.

```
$ nvm use default 8.9.4
```

And the command returns the output.

> Now using node v8.9.4 (npm v5.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu there is a potential issue if you are running a non-interactive shell, for example from a cronjob, or an init or upstart script.

Ubuntu's default `.bashrc` has this guard at the top which drops out early if the shell is non-interactive:

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

So in order to get NVM loaded for non-interactive scripts, you can edit `~/.bashrc` and move NVM's init to the top of the file, just above the guard.

Even safer is to *copy* the NVM init so it appears twice.  That will address the concern mentioned in other answers, when other lines are modifying the `PATH` after NVM.  NVM doesn't seem to mind being run twice, although it does slow down the shell startup a little.

Answer (score 0):

In the nvm autoload script from the github I had to chage

`local node_version="$(nvm version)"` to `local node_version="$(node -v)"`

There was a local install of nvm on my system in my path so `nvm version` kept saying system no matter what

Answer (score 0):

1.- Install via homebrew

2.- Because I am using zsh terminal, in  `~/.zshrc` add this lines, if you are using bash you will need to put that lines in `~/.bash_profile`

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ref:](https://www.willandskill.se/en/articles/how-to-fix-eacces-errors-with-npm-on-macos) The issue that is causing this is related to the fact that the folder NPM is trying to access/write to is not owned by the user that is executing the command

The run the commands stated below and You should be good to go!

```js
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Try running npm install -g ... or npm uninstall -g ... without sudo and it should run without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing another answer out there for Mac + VS Code users.

In my case, I tried `nvm alias default node` as well as `nvm alias default <desired version number>`.  None of those worked, while I was trying it in the VS Code integrated terminal.

Then I realized that when I did `node -v` in the regular terminal, it was remembering the switched version, so I just tried quitting and reopening VS Code.  After reopening the integrated terminal, the node version was updated.  Sometimes it's just something internal to VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution when using `bash` shell. After you set your default version (using for example `nvm alias default stable`), simply add this line to your `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_profile` after the other NVM stuff:

```
nvm use default > /dev/null
```