# Set up nvm to properly work with npm and grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, nvm

I'm somewhat new to web app development, and ran through the Yeoman tutorial, which uses `yo`, `grunt`, `bower`, and `angular`.

I had used homebrew to install `node` and `npm`, but kept getting errors with `npm` due to some permissions and whatnot. I uninstalled `node` using `brew`, and instead used `nvm` to install `node` and `npm`, which no longer gives me errors.

BUT, `nvm` is somewhat annoying. I understand it's a `node` version manager, and I'm fine with having to `nvm use 0.10` every time I open a shell. But now, whenever I want to `grunt serve` my web app from a new shell, I need to install grunt-cli:

```
nvm use 0.10
npm install -g grunt-cli
# ...
grunt serve
```

Is `grunt-cli` not installing globally? Or is it meaningless, because `npm` doesn't 'stick around' between different shells?

Basically, I'm fine with just using one version of node right now. How do I set up `nvm`, `npm`, and `grunt` so I don't have to re-install `grunt` every time I open a new shell?

Comment: about two weeks later, and the problem seemed to have resolved itself. I can now `grunt serve` without calling nvm or npm at all.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as you did: I need to run `nvm use` and `npm install` every time to be able to launch grunt.. Let me know if you ever find out how the problem got solved.

Comment: i believe `nvm alias default v0.10.33` (or whatever version you want to use) will resolve most issues. this means you won't have to type `nvm use` every time you open a new shell. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585261/nvm-keeps-forgetting-node-in-new-terminal-session

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it. You should answer your own question.

Comment: This issue is really annoying. For me the fix was to use `nvm use <version>` several times, then `npm install grunt`. Error appeared then I finally was able to install all packages including grunt that was in package.json. Then at last I could use grunt ....

Comment: Workaround: Run the locally installed version of grunt directly: `./node_modules/.bin/grunt` instead of the global `grunt` command.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your command prompt and try "nvm alias default ". If you want to use version "0.12.7" then your command will be "nvm alias default 0.12.7" and to cross check if the version is used globally open a new command prompt and use command "node -v".

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using nvm use everytime you could leave an .nvmrc file

As from the [docs](https://github.com/creationix/nvm):

```
echo "0.12" >> .nvmrc
```

Now the next time you enter that directory nvm will read that file and load that specific version.

You can check if its working with

```
nvm use
```