# nvm alias default not working in MacOS Capitan EL

Tags: node.js, osx-elcapitan, nvm

My nvm keep forgetting about the node environment ever since I upgraded to Yosemite(A few months ago)/Capitan EL(I upgraded this week) even though I did

```
nvm alias default 0.12
```

Hilariously, it told me after I hit enter

```
default -> 0.12 (-> v0.12.8)
```

But when I opened a new terminal it said node: command is not found!!

There are a couple of solutions I tried so far:

- I have tried using `brew uninstall nvm` & `brew install nvm`
- as well as the installing script, since brew complaint it doesn't work with the pre-released OS(which is actually GA right now)
- I double checked **bash_profile** do have the following lines

  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm

  source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh

Unfortunately, none of them works. Have anyone run into a similar issue before?

Thanks!

Comment: Just checking, does `nvm use 0.12` actually load the correct nvm for you? Using the `alias` did not work for me as well, but what I did was merely add `nvm use <version> > /dev/null` in my bash_profile for it to load.

Comment: if you run `NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm` and `$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh` from command line, does it still throw the error? Would be good if you had the error message shown.

Comment: Also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585261/nvm-keeps-forgetting-node-in-new-terminal-session?rq=1 in case you have not read this thread.

Comment: Thanks @CKD. I tried to run the command manually but it still give me the error. I ended up doing exactly the same as you do. I guess it should be a temporarily solution and need really look into why this is happening any way.

Comment: Did you install using brew or with the `curl` command? The recommended solution on the nvm is to follow these https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script.

Comment: Also can you edit your question to have the exact error message thrown when you run `NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm` and `$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh`

Answer (score 1):

This is merely a temporary solution, however, it works.

1. Add `nvm use stable` in `~/.bash_profile`(or whatever version you want to use to replace *stable*)
2. Save the file
3. Do `source ~/.bash_profile` after this or simply open a new terminal tab.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on El Capitan

```
brew uninstall nvm
brew install nvm
mkdir ~/.nvm
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
 . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh"
```

It said that .nvm folder already existed but I ignored that.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this command in MacOS el capitan

```
$> nvm alias default v6.4.0
```

It worked as expected. Please notice the small **v** before the version number.

And finally, just if it helps, I used this command to install nvm as is described in the nvm project [readme](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

```
$> curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
```