# How to use homebrew nodejs

Tags: node.js, homebrew

As in the below image, I have two node versions. I have no idea how I got this. When I check the node version it shows **14.12.0** but it is not in use. How can I use the latest version **15.7.0** of the `node` that is already installed using brew?

[image]

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43220802/13126651?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Not really. I probably need to link the brew one but don't know how!