# VSCode Gatsy Debug Error with SourceMaps

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, source-maps, gatsby

I was trying to set up VSCode to be able to debug Gatsby code.
I am new to Javascript sourcemaps which seem to be the cause of the problem.

I am seeing the following error on launch:

```
Cannot launch program "c:\Gatsby\myprogram\node_modules\.bin\gatsby" because corresponding Javascript cannot be found.
```

I verified that the path to the file gatsby in the error exists.

This is the file that I am using for  launch.json:

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
    "name": "Launch",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/gatsby",
    "args": ["develop", "-p", "7777"],
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "preLaunchTask": null,
    "runtimeExecutable": null,
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "--nolazy"
    ],
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
      "DEBUG": "gatsby:*"
    },
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "outFiles": []
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by using globally installed gatsby-cli's `gatsby` instead of the one in node_modules. So:

```
npm install --global gatsby-cli
```

and then (since I use node/npm etc under nvm):

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch 'gatsby develop'",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "program": "${env:HOME}/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/gatsby",
        "args": [
            "develop"
        ],
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "preLaunchTask": null,
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development",
            "DEBUG": "gatsby:*"
        },
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outFiles": []
    }
```

worked for me.
I'm on OSX though, more changes may be needed for your Windows setup.

Also: to use node under nvm with VSCode, I used the default alias method from here: [Visual Studio Code to use node version specified by NVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700432/visual-studio-code-to-use-node-version-specified-by-nvm)

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-the-build-process/)

> **VS Code Debugger (Auto-Config)**

> Using VS Code’s integrated terminal run `node --nolazy node_modules/.bin/gatsby develop --inspect-brk` instead of gatsby develop or `node --nolazy --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/gatsby` build instead of `gatsby build`

> **VS Code Debugger (Manual Config)**

> Linux
>
> ```
> {
>   "version": "0.2.0",
>   "configurations": [
>     {
>       "name": "Gatsby develop",
>       "type": "pwa-node",
>       "request": "launch",
>       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/gatsby",
>       "args": ["develop"],
>       "env": {
>         "PARCEL_WORKERS": "0",
>         "GATSBY_CPU_COUNT": "1",
>       },
>       "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
>       "console": "integratedTerminal"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "Gatsby build",
>       "type": "pwa-node",
>       "request": "launch",
>       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/gatsby",
>       "args": ["build"],
>       "env": {
>         "PARCEL_WORKERS": "0",
>         "GATSBY_CPU_COUNT": "1",
>       },
>       "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
>       "console": "integratedTerminal"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> Windows
>
> ```
> {
>   "version": "0.2.0",
>   "configurations": [
>     {
>       "name": "Gatsby develop",
>       "type": "pwa-node",
>       "request": "launch",
>       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/gatsby",
>       "windows": {
>         "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gatsby/dist/bin/gatsby"
>       },
>       "args": ["develop"],
>       "env": {
>         "PARCEL_WORKERS": "0",
>         "GATSBY_CPU_COUNT": "1",
>       },
>       "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
>       "console": "integratedTerminal"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "Gatsby build",
>       "type": "pwa-node",
>       "request": "launch",
>       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/gatsby",
>       "windows": {
>         "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gatsby/dist/bin/gatsby"
>       },
>       "args": ["build"],
>       "env": {
>         "PARCEL_WORKERS": "0",
>         "GATSBY_CPU_COUNT": "1",
>       },
>       "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
>       "console": "integratedTerminal"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```