# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib in VSCode Terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal, visual-studio-code

For my case, i only get the error when opening accessing terminal (zsh) via VS Code.

Upon opening VS Code terminal OR running `node` command, i get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
[1]    4506 abort      node
```

However, it runs fine when running via iTerm. Tried running `brew update` and `brew upgrade` and a few other recommended answers.

Anything am i missing?

Comment: New install of VS code and new macbook - same issue. macOS Mojave and VS 1.31.0

Comment: [2020 answer] Here is the related issue answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955091/7059946

Comment: 2 years 6 months later, i encountered this problem again and am glad that @Jason's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54662431/8096221) helped me resolve this again

Comment: Again the same issue. I've migrated to Apple M1, and some folders seem messed up. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69702082/1779739) helped me to resolve the problem.

```shell
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm && rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
```

Answer (score 45):

Piggybacking off [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54662431/564479), another option is to just run

```
brew upgrade node
```

Comment: Work! 10.14.6 macOS

Comment: I got this error, but this answer still worked for me (solved the problem despite the error message) `Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.12.3`

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!  I had already run `brew upgrade` and `brew cleanup` (or whatever it is) and was panicking!

Answer (score 34):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11713#issuecomment-289670329)

Run this

```
brew uninstall node icu4c
brew install node
```

Comment: Found the answer here--thanks! `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c` avoided issues with several related dependencies, including postgresql.

Comment: I ran into this issue after upgrading from Mojave to Monterey (although it was /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.70.dylib).  In addition to the answers here I somehow had a bad Node install lying around and had to `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/node\@12` then `brew install node` and now things are back to normal.

Answer (score 23):

You might follow these steps.

```
> which node
/usr/local/bin/node
> rm /usr/local/bin/node
> brew unlink node
> brew link --overwrite node
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: This is the only answer which worked (...like a charm)!

Comment: For me, I ran these steps, but I got the same error afterwards. So I also `brew uninstall node` and then `brew install node` and everything worked again.

Comment: Followed these steps. The problem was not solved. `brew upgrade node` helped me. (macOS Big Sur)

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. Exactly what I needed to fix this issue.

Answer (score 11):

A `brew reinstall icu4c` fixed the problem on macOS 10.15.6.

It also helps to watch your logs when starting a broken package (node, pg, etc. – for pg it's `tail -f /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@11.log` – not the server log).

Comment: Yes! that did it for me

Comment: That did it. You saved my day!

Comment: I needed to do this after upgrading to Mac OS 13.2.1. `brew upgrade node` didn't do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall VSCode using the apple silicon download link [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/download%5B1%5D%20then%20it%20correctly%20uses%20the%20%60/opt/homebrew%60%20folder.%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://code.visualstudio.com/download#). If I installed the from the command line it kept using the old `/usr/bin` folders instead of the new M1 brew folder `/opt/homebrew`