cannot install Reveal.js on Mac
I'm trying to do Full Setup as documented here: https://revealjs.com/installation/
And the step 3 cd reveal.js && npm install fails as follows:
Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.74.dylib
  Referenced from: <E75B5D55-A56F-38D1-828D-ACC88DC8B337> 
   /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/22.2.0/bin/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.74.dylib' (no such file), 
  '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.74.dylib' 
  (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.74.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c@76/76.1_1/lib/libicui18n.74.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c@76/76.1_1/lib/libicui18n.74.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c@76/76.1_1/lib/libicui18n.74.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      npm install

How should I fix it?

seems your node.js installation is messed up. I'd try reinstalling that with homebrew. or uninstall your existing node.js and use something like https://volta.sh/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604121/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-63-dylib-in-vscode/79251008#79251008 is a very similar issue with many suggested solutions. Your node, installed by Homebrew, is referencing a nonexistent file. There is probably a new version (76) of that icu4c file in the same directory where it can't find the 74 one. If you get a different version of node it might reference the correct icu4c that you have installed.
