# How to find NODE_MODULE_VERSION?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to know `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` in Node.js? If yes, then how?
I am interested specifically in the VSCode's builtin Node.js, but maybe Node.js doesn't expose the variable, but VSCode API does?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code to use node version specified by NVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700432/visual-studio-code-to-use-node-version-specified-by-nvm)

Comment: @J.Meijer Thanks, but that's not even close.

Comment: @Was'SiimBenHssen No it doesn't.

Comment: Will do, but from your question, it sounded like you want to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To access in node what electron refers to as `NODE_MODULE_VERSION`, you use:

`process.versions.modules`

---

Other values in that object:

```
> console.log(process.versions)
{
  "http_parser": "2.8.0",
  "node": "8.16.2",
  "v8": "6.2.414.78",
  "uv": "1.23.2",
  "zlib": "1.2.11",
  "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",
  "modules": "57",
  "nghttp2": "1.39.2",
  "napi": "4",
  "openssl": "1.0.2s",
  "icu": "60.1",
  "unicode": "10.0",
  "cldr": "32.0",
  "tz": "2017c"
}
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know what is the relation between `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` and `process.versions.modules`. You defined that in the first sentence "what electron refers to as".

Comment: FYI- to get this from command line, you can do `node -e "console.log(process.versions)"`

Comment: @kip or `node -p "process.versions.modules"` etc

Comment: If I need the nodejs `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` to match the electron `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` (the same module needs to be shared used by both electron and nodejs modules) can I assume I need the node.js version to match the electron version?