# Cannot change node version in VS Code terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, nvm

I'm working on Mac and I cannot change node version from terminal window in VS Code
[image]

What's interesting, when I open iTerm I have no problems with switching versions. So the problem only seems to appear on VS Code.

Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: When you open a new terminal, what type of terminal does it open?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha, zsh

Comment: Is it possible that there are some path discrepencies between zsh and whatever shell is used by iTerm?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible. Could you please tell me how to verify it?

Comment: Issue the command "echo $PATH" and see if they're different.

Comment: @ShafiqJetha, path to node version is the same.

Comment: I don't think I can be of any more help to you. I've added a few more tags to this question to hopefully get other people involved. I hope you're able to resolve your problem.

Comment: For anyone having same problem. Just did what's in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53596328/6808696 and it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

vscode has a [shell integration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal), which you can [configure](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration). e.g. placing the following configuration in your vscode settings

```json
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

or you can use the [shell launcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher) plugin, which supports launch multiple shell configurations in the terminal.