# Enforcing node version on eslint server

Tags: node.js, eslint, visual-studio-code, nvm

I have a work project where I need to enforce an older version *(`10.24.1`)* of [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs)  on [eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint).

I'm managing my node version via [nvm](/questions/tagged/nvm). Specifically, I've set my default version of [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) to said `10.24.1` via

```
$ nvm alias default 10
```

[image]

This also checks out with running version and set [eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint) env version.

```
$ node -v
$ npx eslint --env-info
```

[image]

However, locally my ESLint seems to crash when viewing files in [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code).

[image]

I also tried specifying in local configuration in `package.json`:

```json
"engines": {
  "node": ">=10.24.1"
}
```

This however seems to take no effect. So I'm not really sure what else I should do.

> **Is there any idea on how to enforce the [eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint) server to run on my specified node version instead of the v14.6.0?**

Comment: i think this covers your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700432/visual-studio-code-to-use-node-version-specified-by-nvm/48710384

Comment: Speficially the default alias woked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44707192/5512705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.nvmrc` and `.node-version` files to your project directory

.nvmrc file content:

```
10.24.1
```

.node-version file content:

```
10.24.1
```

And after,

`npm i -g @typescript-eslint` should fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

For users of VS Code add the following setting to your settings.json:

```json
"eslint.runtime": "node"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is use the setting `eslint.runtime` to specify the Node version you want the ESLint server to run on. There is no need to set the `nvmrc` nor to reinstall the package.

```json
// settings.json
{
  "eslint.runtime": "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.1/bin/node"
}
```

If you don't know where your node binary file is, you can use `where node` to find out if you are using a Unix-like terminal.

After saving the settings, **an important thing is to restart your VSCode** (it might not be enough if you only restart the ESLint server). You should see it run on a different version after that in the VSCode.

[image: choose node version in ESLint server]