# how to config vscode to use system-available nodejs?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-extensions

I run VSCode

```
Version: 1.64.2
Commit: f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326
Date: 2022-02-09T22:02:29.527Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.16.9-200.fc35.x86_64
```

Note the

```
Node.js: 14.16.0
```

and, for ESLint logs

```
[Info  - 6:57:38 PM] ESLint server is starting
[Info  - 6:57:38 PM] ESLint server running in node v14.16.0
[Info  - 6:57:38 PM] ESLint server is running.
```

On my system, @ user shell,

```
node -v
    v17.5.0
```

not `v14.16.0`

Where/how does VSCode get told to use/recognize system-available node?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code to use node version specified by NVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700432/visual-studio-code-to-use-node-version-specified-by-nvm)

Comment: I don't use nvm, so lots of that doesn't apply. I did try creating a launch.json and pointing at my node bin with the `runtimeExecutable` key.  No change.  Still seems to competely ignore my v17.5.0 node.