# Parsing error: __classPrivateFieldGet(...).at is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, react-typescript, typescript-eslint

I fount the error saying "Parsing error: __classPrivateFieldGet(...).at is not a function (eslint)
[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei0He.png)

```
Parsing error: __classPrivateFieldGet(...).at is not a functioneslint
```

There are errors in every first line in every tsx files.

My project is made with typescript, React.

Here's my .eslintrc.js

```
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  parserOptions: {
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
  },
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    sourceType: 'module',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  ignorePatterns: [".eslintrc.js"], 
  rules: {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"] }],
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/semi': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/space-before-function-paren': 'off',
  },
};
```

and this is tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "importHelpers": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

The application is running well though....

Can anyone know what `__classPrivateFieldGet` is and how I can fix this?

I tried to find some solutions from googling, but I couldn't find anything...

Comment: `__classPrivateFieldGet` is probably a generated function used as part of the implementation of transpiling support for private fields. Somewhat tangential, but: What environment do you plan to run your code in that you need to compile it down to ***ES5***?? All major (and probably most minor) browsers support at **least** ES2015 (aka "ES6"), and all major ones support at least ES2022 (which includes private fields).

Comment: Tried target: es2022 but I'm still getting this error.  Possibly strange in light of comment from @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this exact issue. I was able to fix it by installing an earlier version of my ES Lint tools. I am not exactly sure which package or version started causing this issue, but I changed the following eslint versions and it fixed it for me. If you use prettier as your formatter, you will also have to downgrade that.

My advice is to try downgrading any eslint libraries you have installed. Update your package.json with the earlier versions and run `npm install`, then retry.

package.json:

```json
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I downgraded eslint like above versions, and fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @matthew G (I lack the reputation to comment under his post, or else would) - but downgrading specifically these two dependencies to these versions solved the problem for me:

```
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.5.0",
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I referenced your comment too and downgraded especially eslint/eslint-plugin and eslint/parser! :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just setting the @typescript-eslint/parser package to "6.5.0."

`"@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.5.0",`

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was my node version. Upgrading to node v18 from v15 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using NodeJS version `^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0`.

This error appears when you use `typescript-eslint@^7.3.0` running under NodeJS version lower than `^18.18.0`. (It was `v15.14.0` for me).

`typescript-eslint@^7.3.0` requires NodeJS `^18.18.0 || >=20.0.0`

https://typescript-eslint.io/users/dependency-versions/#node

---

That's why suggested solutions for downgrading a `typescript-eslint` actually works. But doesn't seem to be a right solution.
The right one actually was given by @Jose-Browne

---

Also be aware that your IDE (VSCode) uses right NodeJS version. As when VSCode starts it turns on a default node version from `nvm`.

This issue described in following:
[Visual Studio Code to use node version specified by NVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700432/visual-studio-code-to-use-node-version-specified-by-nvm)

Answer (score -1):

I removed the commented lines in the image below from my package.json file and added the two lines below it. The commented lines came default when I created the project with `npx create-next-app`
[image: package.json]