# How to configure the shell that vscode extensions use?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode on Mac with the following settings.

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
      "path": "zsh",
      "args": [
        "-l"
      ]
    },
  },
}
```

And I have [nvm autoload configuration for zsh](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#zsh) in my `.zprofile` which works correctly even in the terminal on vscode.

Now when I commit using the git extension GUI of vscode, (it seems) it doesn't use zsh as the node version the extension uses is not correct.
[image: vscode extension node version is incorrect]

The above project uses node v16 which is specified by `.nvmrc`, but the git extension uses v20 which is my default node version.

This problem could be fixed by [changing my default node version to 16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44707192/10694438), but I want the default version to be 20 and want vscode to use a specific node version per workspace.

How can I make extensions use specific node version, respect `.nvmrc`, or use specific shell per workspace?

Comment: try the terminal automation profile setting? have you tried changing other shell config to see which shell is being used?