How to use nodemon in VS Code with a specific node.js version?
I know I can set up VS Code to use nodemon by putting a launch.json like
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "my program",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
    }]
}

But how do I make VS Code and nodemon use a specific node.js version for my program app.js?
Answer to the suggestion in the comments:
The alias-default-solution does not change the node version when nodemon is used and the other solutions go after the node binary but here the binary is nodemon. I do not figure out how nodemon chooses the node version to run.

Do you use nvm?

Sure. Do you know a possibility with nvm to set a specific node.js version for nodemon in vscode?

Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44700432/7353417

Does this answer your question? Visual Studio Code to use node version specified by NVM
