# Node version reset when computer reboots

Tags: node.js, nvm

I installed Node 9.11.1 using `nvm install` and my projects can use the updated features but whenever I reboot I get reset to v6.10.1. I've checked this answer [nvm keeps "forgetting" node in new terminal session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585261/nvm-keeps-forgetting-node-in-new-terminal-session) and upon typing `nvm list` I see that the green arrow points to v6.10.1 but v9.11.1 is installed.

What do I need to do to make Node default to 9.11.1 after a reboot?

Answer (score 32):

To set default version type:

```
nvm alias default 9.11.1
```

After a reboot you will have 9.11.1 version.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work upon rebooting. This is the answer I got from researching.

Comment: If you type `nvm list` the green arrow now is pointing to v9.11.1?

Comment: Yes, but I used the same command you made an answer before I tried my solution. I'm not sure why it would not persist upon rebooting.

Comment: mine also does not presist

Comment: It worked with my setup. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 running node v10.23.3 for nuxt development.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow top answer didn't help me, but similar command helped:

```sh
nvm alias default node
```