# NVM: npm install -g keeps using wrong version of node

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm trying to install a package called `expo-cli`, but it is failing because npm keeps using the wrong version of node.

I'm setting my node version to v12.4.0, which I confirm is set. But when I run `npm install -g expo-cli`, it keeps using `v9.10.0`

```
➜  ~ nvm current
v12.4.0
➜  ~ node -v
v12.4.0
➜  ~ npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.

> @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.9 preinstall /Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin
> node platform.js

/Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/bin/expo-cli -> /Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
/Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/bin/expo -> /Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js

> fsevents@1.2.9 install /Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install
```

How do I change npm to use node v12.4.0?

Expo-cli fails without the right version of node.

```
➜  ~ expo init my-app
zsh: command not found: expo
➜  ~ nvm list
         v8.0.0
        v9.10.0
        v10.8.0
->      v12.4.0
default -> v12.4.0
node -> stable (-> v12.4.0) (default)
stable -> 12.4 (-> v12.4.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.16.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.16.0 (-> N/A)
➜  ~ nvm use v9.10.0
Now using node v9.10.0 (npm v6.9.0)
➜  ~ expo init my-app
/Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js:12
  throw new Error('expo-cli supports Node versions 8.x.x, 10.x.x and newer.');
  ^

Error: expo-cli supports Node versions 8.x.x, 10.x.x and newer.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js:12:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:666:3
```

UPDATE:

```
This is what happens when I try to scope the node version:

➜  ~ nvm run 12.4.0 npm install --latest-npm
Running node v12.4.0 (npm v6.9.0)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/edmundmai/npm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
➜  ~ nvm exec 12.4.0 npm install -g expo-cli
Running node v12.4.0 (npm v6.9.0)
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.

> @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.9 preinstall /Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin
> node platform.js

/Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/bin/expo -> /Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
/Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/bin/expo-cli -> /Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js

> fsevents@1.2.9 install /Users/edmundmai/.nvm/versions/node/v9.10.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install
```

Answer (score 18):

Check ~/.npmrc for a prefix setting that points to the v9.10.0 module install path. That will cause npm to install global packages in the wrong place when using other versions of node.

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config#prefix

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide context on why this is the answer and where did you find this. [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @ArielGro Thanks, I have edited my answer per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: `$ nvm run 12.4.0 npm install -g expo-cli`

or this: `$ nvm exec 12.4.0 npm install -g expo-cli`

For reference: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#usage

Comment: Hi Diego, I tried it but they didn't work, I updated the question with the results

Comment: can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32835618/11734350
The problem is that you have to install nvm again but seems like the shortest path to solve the problem