# How to remove the old version of node js?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have a version of node JS as `8.10.0` on Linux mint.

But I want to install the latest stable version `10.16.0`.
For upgrade node js version I have followed the following steps:

> 1. sudo npm cache clean -f
> 2. sudo npm install -g n
> 3. sudo n stable
> 4. sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/10.16.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node

But it has created a problem, now on command `node -v` I am getting the previous version as `8.10.0` while on run the command as `nodejs -v` I am getting the upgraded version as `10.16.0`.

One more thing which I have noticed here that on command `sudo node -v` it is responding version as `10.16.0`.

How can I upgrade node js version to `10.16.0` so that when I run the command `node -v` and get upgraded stable version?

Why I am getting `nodejs -v` as a command?

Why I am getting different versions on `nodejs -v` and on `node -v`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nvm keeps "forgetting" node in new terminal session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585261/nvm-keeps-forgetting-node-in-new-terminal-session)

Comment: My question is different, it is not about to set the default version. why I am getting nodejs -v as different version and node -v as different???

Comment: Are you using `n` or `nvm`?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -sL https://appsys.com.pk/linux/install-nodejs-10.sh | sudo -E bash -
```

just run this with sudo it will install newest node 10