# Node version is not persisting after update with NVM

Tags: node.js, nvm

I updated my node version from 8.x.x to 13.x.x using the cmds below:

```
nvm install stable
```

Running `node -v` immediately after this, shows the updated version. But re-opening the terminal the older version of node persists.

I had to do: `nvm use 13` to enable node 13.x.x

What is the ideal way to keep using the latest node version with explicitly using `nvm use` every time?

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24585261

Comment: Have you tried using alias: nvm alias default x.x.x

Comment: @GlenK `nvm alias default 13` solved the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nvm alias default 13
```

This solved the issue and set the node version permanent to 13.x.x

Comment: There must be something else going on because that doesn't work on my Mac OS 13.2.1
```
➜  graphqlTest node -v               
v16.13.2
➜  graphqlTest nvm alias default node
default -> node (-> v18.16.0)
➜  graphqlTest node -v               
v16.13.2
```