# nvm: Ubuntu 22.04 keep forgetting "nvm" and others installations made with it

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

## Problem

A days ago updated node and npm using nvm, everything works until shutdown my machine.

Next morning, always get:

```bash
~ nvm
bash: nvm: order not found
```

```bash
~ npm
bash: npm: order not found
```

```bash
~ node --help
bash: node: order not found
```

But everything just works after "sourcing" ".profile", where I save all my variables and modifications to "$PATH":

```bash
~ source .profile

~ nvm
Node Version Manager (v0.39.2)

Note: <version> refers to any version-like string nvm understands. This includes:
  - full or partial version numbers, starting with an optional "v" (0.10, v0.1.2, v1)
  - default (built-in) aliases: node, stable, unstable, iojs, system
  - custom aliases you define with `nvm alias foo`

 Any options that produce colorized output should respect the `--no-colors` option.

Usage:
  nvm --help                                  Show this message
    --no-colors                               Suppress colored output
  nvm --version                               Print out the installed version of nvm
  nvm install [<version>]                     Download and install a <version>. Uses .nvmrc if available and version is omitted.
   The following optional arguments, if provided, must appear directly after `nvm install`:
    -s                                        Skip binary download, install from source only.
    -b                                        Skip source download, install from binary only.
    --reinstall-packages-from=<version>       When installing, reinstall packages installed in <node|iojs|node version number>
    --lts                                     When installing, only select from LTS (long-term support) versions
    --lts=<LTS name>                          When installing, only select from versions for a specific LTS line
    --skip-default-packages                   When installing, skip the default-packages file if it exists
    --latest-npm                              After installing, attempt to upgrade to the latest working npm on the given node version
    --no-progress                             Disable the progress bar on any downloads
    --alias=<name>                            After installing, set the alias specified to the version specified. (same as: nvm alias <name> <version>)
    --default                                 After installing, set default alias to the version specified. (same as: nvm alias default <version>)
  nvm uninstall <version>                     Uninstall a version
  nvm uninstall --lts                         Uninstall using automatic LTS (long-term support) alias `lts/*`, if available.
  nvm uninstall --lts=<LTS name>              Uninstall using automatic alias for provided LTS line, if available.
  nvm use [<version>]                         Modify PATH to use <version>. Uses .nvmrc if available and version is omitted.
   The following optional arguments, if provided, must appear directly after `nvm use`:
    --silent                                  Silences stdout/stderr output
    --lts                                     Uses automatic LTS (long-term support) alias `lts/*`, if available.
    --lts=<LTS name>                          Uses automatic alias for provided LTS line, if available.
  nvm exec [<version>] [<command>]            Run <command> on <version>. Uses .nvmrc if available and version is omitted.
   The following optional arguments, if provided, must appear directly after `nvm exec`:
    --silent                                  Silences stdout/stderr output
    --lts                                     Uses automatic LTS (long-term support) alias `lts/*`, if available.
    --lts=<LTS name>                          Uses automatic alias for provided LTS line, if available.
  nvm run [<version>] [<args>]                Run `node` on <version> with <args> as arguments. Uses .nvmrc if available and version is omitted.
   The following optional arguments, if provided, must appear directly after `nvm run`:
    --silent                                  Silences stdout/stderr output
    --lts                                     Uses automatic LTS (long-term support) alias `lts/*`, if available.
    --lts=<LTS name>                          Uses automatic alias for provided LTS line, if available.
  nvm current                                 Display currently activated version of Node
  nvm ls [<version>]                          List installed versions, matching a given <version> if provided
    --no-colors                               Suppress colored output
    --no-alias                                Suppress `nvm alias` output
  nvm ls-remote [<version>]                   List remote versions available for install, matching a given <version> if provided
    --lts                                     When listing, only show LTS (long-term support) versions
    --lts=<LTS name>                          When listing, only show versions for a specific LTS line
    --no-colors                               Suppress colored output
  nvm version <version>                       Resolve the given description to a single local version
  nvm version-remote <version>                Resolve the given description to a single remote version
    --lts                                     When listing, only select from LTS (long-term support) versions
    --lts=<LTS name>                          When listing, only select from versions for a specific LTS line
  nvm deactivate                              Undo effects of `nvm` on current shell
    --silent                                  Silences stdout/stderr output
  nvm alias [<pattern>]                       Show all aliases beginning with <pattern>
    --no-colors                               Suppress colored output
  nvm alias <name> <version>                  Set an alias named <name> pointing to <version>
  nvm unalias <name>                          Deletes the alias named <name>
  nvm install-latest-npm                      Attempt to upgrade to the latest working `npm` on the current node version
  nvm reinstall-packages <version>            Reinstall global `npm` packages contained in <version> to current version
  nvm unload                                  Unload `nvm` from shell
  nvm which [current | <version>]             Display path to installed node version. Uses .nvmrc if available and version is omitted.
    --silent                                  Silences stdout/stderr output when a version is omitted
  nvm cache dir                               Display path to the cache directory for nvm
  nvm cache clear                             Empty cache directory for nvm
  nvm set-colors [<color codes>]              Set five text colors using format "yMeBg". Available when supported.
                                               Initial colors are:
                                                   b  y  g  r  e
                                               Color codes:
                                                 r/R = red / bold red
                                                 g/G = green / bold green
                                                 b/B = blue / bold blue
                                                 c/C = cyan / bold cyan
                                                 m/M = magenta / bold magenta
                                                 y/Y = yellow / bold yellow
                                                 k/K = black / bold black
                                                 e/W = light grey / white

Example:
  nvm install 8.0.0                     Install a specific version number
  nvm use 8.0                           Use the latest available 8.0.x release
  nvm run 6.10.3 app.js                 Run app.js using node 6.10.3
  nvm exec 4.8.3 node app.js            Run `node app.js` with the PATH pointing to node 4.8.3
  nvm alias default 8.1.0               Set default node version on a shell
  nvm alias default node                Always default to the latest available node version on a shell

  nvm install node                      Install the latest available version
  nvm use node                          Use the latest version
  nvm install --lts                     Install the latest LTS version
  nvm use --lts                         Use the latest LTS version

  nvm set-colors cgYmW                  Set text colors to cyan, green, bold yellow, magenta, and white

Note:
  to remove, delete, or uninstall nvm - just remove the `$NVM_DIR` folder (usually `~/.nvm`)
```

I don't understand why, because the nvm folder alredy exist:

```bash
~ find $HOME -name .nvm
/home/{my_username}/.nvm
```

And even the variable "$NVM_DIR" is alredy set, and is identified from the start:

```bash
~ echo $NVM_DIR
/home/{my_username}/.nvm
```

## What I Tried

1. Tried moving the variable declaration in my ".profile" file, cause read that modifing the $PATH after exporting nvm variables can cause some problems. This according to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47883587/18646685) in other post.
2. Tried modifiying the variable of nvm in .profile, because in the [main page](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#manual-upgrade) appear other:

   - Before:

   ```bash
   export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This load>
   ```

   - After:

   ```bash
   export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
   ```

## Important

1. $NVM_DIR is set before sourcing, so .profile is read at system starting
2. nvm: vr. 0.39.2
3. Ubuntu: vr. 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: yes i can confirm this regression, not persisting alias default anymore

Comment: Do you have the bash shell as default? I had problems when I had fish shell as default.