# nvm not properly setting up node for new shell

Tags: node.js, macos, zsh, nvm

I installed nvm (node version manager) on my new M1 Max MacStudio via Homebrew.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but if I start a new zsh shell and type in `node -v` I get `command not found`.

I'm not 100% sure what I'm supposed to see, but `nvm list` shows I have v.20.10.0 and v.18.19.0 installed.

`nvm use v20.10.0` works and then I'm fine, but if I start another new shell I end up in the same place with no working node command

`~/.zprofile` has

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

if [ -f ~/.zshrc ]; then
. ~/.zshrc
fi
```

and `~/.zshrc` contains

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

in it.  I'm not quite sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried the steps in [Troubleshooting on macOS](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#troubleshooting-on-macos)? In particular have you tried restarting `Terminal`?

Comment: Not directly related to your question: I don't think it is a good idea to source .zshrc from your .zprofile, because .zshrc should contain only stuff relevant for interactive shells. If you need environment  settings in all zsh shells (including those started from cron jobs),  put the environment settings into .zshenv. If you only need these settings in interactive shells, and in scripts spawned from those, put them solely into .zshrc. In many cases, .zshenv is a good place for such stuff, because it is sourced by every zsh.

Comment: I didn’t originally have it in there, so i don't think it has any bearing on my current problem.  

What should be in zprofile?

Comment: Actually, I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585261/nvm-keeps-forgetting-node-in-new-terminal-session) answers it.  Typing `nvm use v20.10.0` and then `nvm alias default node` seems to set it up for future shell (re)starts

Not sure wha the best way to mark this solved is (new to Stack Overflow)